# Form submision error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller like below which I use to sign up,  but each time I submit the form I see this error:

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$db

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 954
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');


    }

    public function sign_up(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is $db? Looks like its missing...

Comment: This question doesn't have complete information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your database parameters in `/application/config/database.php`? If not, you won't be able pass validation because of the `is_unique[users.username]` rule you've added to the username parameter.

I am not sure if you have to explicitly load the database class before calling an `is_unique` parameter, as I always autoload that class, but I suspect you should have to.

**Edit**

Digging into the system files. `system/libraries/Form_validation.php` has the following on line 954:

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
    {
        list($table, $field)=explode('.', $field);
        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));

        return $query->num_rows() === 0;
```

This indicates that the CI instance is looking for the database parameters to make the check, but the Form Validation library does not load the Database class itself, so you should either load it in the controller yourself, or set it to autoload.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace username rule:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
```

With this rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
```

Just remove :

> |is_unique[users.username]